# PHP Server Code to Process an Image Upload

Tags: php, image, sockets, stream

I would like to write some code in PHP to process the server side of an image stream being uploaded via a socket connection. I already have the client side code which is written in java

```
    Socket soc;
    BufferedImage img = null;
    soc = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4000);       
    try 
    {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("blake-rig.jpg"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();           
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();          
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();                       
        OutputStream out = soc.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);            
        dos.writeInt(bytes.length);
        dos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);          
        dos.close();
        out.close();            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.err.println("Exception " + ex);
        soc.close();
    }
    soc.close();
}
```

I have found this [[server code]](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/downloading_uploading_images.htm) to process the image, but it is also written in java rather than PHP:

```
  class Server {
  public static void main(String  args[]) throws Exception{
  ServerSocket server=null;
  Socket socket;
  server = new ServerSocket(4000);
  System.out.println("Server Waiting for image");

  socket = server.accept();
  System.out.println("Client connected.");
  
  InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
  DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);

  int len = dis.readInt();
  System.out.println("Image Size: " + len/1024 + "KB");
  
  byte[] data = new byte[len];
  dis.readFully(data);
  dis.close();
  in.close();

  InputStream ian = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
  BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(ian);
  }
  }
```

The problem I am having is that I am unable to find any code examples or explanations which would help me write the equivalent code to read the incoming image stream in PHP. I would really appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks

Comment: Before you get too far with this, how are you going to serve this? PHP is normally served behind a web server that is already listening on ports 80 and 443, but it doesn't get "woken up" until an HTTP request comes in. You could also create a service/daemon that is continuously listening, and register that with your OS, but I'll warning you that PHP doesn't have a good reputation for long-running tasks, and most people install additional tools to restart PHP every once in a while.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris.  The reason I want to process an image upload this way is because the upload is coming from a Desktop Journal App written in Java, and I need to synch the contents of each journal entry (which includes images) with a web version of the software written in PHP/Javascript.  The server socket through which the image upload passes only need to be open whilst a journal entry is being synched.  Its not something that need to run continuously in the background.  I am just a bit stuck on how to process the php server side of the image upload.

Comment: "not something that need to run continuously in the background" - Unless I'm misunderstanding, that is not correct. Your Java app needs to send the image to something. If that something isn't running, something else needs to wake it up. So something needs to be continuously running somewhere so that Java can send an image to it. This gets a million times easier if your Java app can just send the image over HTTP in a POST. Then you have a web server running continuously that invokes PHP if/when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Chris.  I will look into sending the image as a POST as you suggest.